Word VBA macro with multiple find/replace options for single-word selection only works if the selection contains the first F/R option
I have created a series of macros to select the next word, ignore the space and punctuation, and replace the word based on multiple find/replace options. I actually have 12 macros that are all based on this principal.
I have longer, more bloated versions of these macros that have worked great for years, but I'm now looking to streamline and trim them down and make them less bloated. The macros are grouped in four groups of three, with each group doing identical functions with different strings of text: first macro replacing a single-word selection, the second macro replacing all "finds" on a line, and the third macro replacing all "finds" in a (user-chosen) selection.
So far my single-word macro is working - sort of - but only if the selected word is the first word in the find string:
It was the first of October.
With my cursor somewhere on "the," the macro will replace "first" with "1st." But if the selected word was any other ordinal (second through ninth), it just ends up with the cursor at the beginning of the ordinal word - no error message.
Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance for any help!
Karen :)
```
Sub ReplaceNextOrdinal()

Dim StrFind As String, StrRepl As String
    
StrFind = "first,second,third,fourth,fifth,sixth,seventh,eighth,ninth"
StrRepl = "1st,2nd,3rd,4th,5th,6th,7th,8th,9th"

        Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1
        
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = Split(StrFind, ",")
            .Replacement.Text = Split(StrRepl, ",")
            .IgnorePunct = True
            .IgnoreSpace = True
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
        End With

End Sub


Where is i coming from?  You seem to be missing a loop of some sort.

Hi, Tim - Ooh, good catch! When I first started the process of modifying this series of macros, I went shopping in my own stash and online and cobbled together and experimented with different code iterations to get my results.
This one was the first to give me partial success. It was originally part of  a "Next I" loop that was intended for multiple replacements throughout an entire document, so I trimmed it down and forgot to take out  the remaining (I) codes. However, now that I have, my macro doesn't work at all! The debugger takes me to the .Text line. Thoughts?

You're missing a loop over the array from Split()
Sub ReplaceNextOrdinal()
    'use const for fixed values
    Const StrFind = "first,second,third,fourth,fifth,sixth,seventh,eighth,ninth"
    Const StrRepl = "1st,2nd,3rd,4th,5th,6th,7th,8th,9th"
    
    Dim arrF, arrR, i As Long
    
    arrF = Split(StrFind, ",")
    arrR = Split(StrRepl, ",")
    
    Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdWord, Count:=1
    Selection.Expand unit:=wdWord 'select the word
    
    Debug.Print "Checking: " & Selection.Text
    For i = LBound(arrF) To UBound(arrF)
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = arrF(i)
            .MatchWholeWord = True
            .Replacement.Text = arrR(i)
            .IgnorePunct = True
            .IgnoreSpace = True
            If .Execute(Replace:=wdReplaceOne) Then Exit For  'found one!
        End With
    Next i
End Sub


Something more sophisticated for you. The code below works across any selected range, allowing you to process multiple ordinals at once, plus it superscripts them. As coded, you can include ordinals greater than ten, too, all the way up to ninety-nine.
Sub ReplaceSelectedOrdinals()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ArrFnd As Variant, ArrRep As Variant, RngFnd As Range, i As Long
'Array of Find expressions
ArrFnd = Array("first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth", "seventh", "eighth", "ninth", "tenth")
ArrRep = Array("1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th", "6th", "7th", "8th", "9th", "10th")
Set RngFnd = ActiveDocument.Range(Selection.Words.First.Start, Selection.Words.Last.End)
For i = 0 To UBound(ArrFnd)
  With RngFnd.Duplicate
    With .Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .IgnorePunct = True
      .IgnoreSpace = True
      .MatchWholeWord = True
      .Text = ArrFnd(i)
    End With
    Do While .Find.Execute
      If .InRange(RngFnd) Then
        .Text = ArrRep(i)
        .Start = .Characters.Last.Previous.Start
        .Font.Superscript = True
      Else
        Exit Do
      End If
    Loop
  End With
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Hi, Paul - It's good to see you here. I must humbly admit I do not understand enough about arrays and split strings to understand the differences operationwise between your Array-centric solution and my original Split String-centric solution that Tim helped me get in a working state.
In addition to the initial set of 12 single-use macros, it occurs to me I can now embark on the daunting task of converting THOUSANDS of lines of code in my related global macros Find/Replace-centric macros. But first, I'd like to understand the differences between the two possible solutions.  Thanks!

I should clarify my previous comment more. I'd love to know more about the pros and cons of choosing one solution over the other, especially any limitations or caveats to be aware of.
FYI, one issue I've encountered with the Split String-centric method is not being able to break the Const lines. It does not like the "space _" at all.
I also do not need the superscript option for my purposes, but thanks for thinking of that. And interestingly, I thought I would never need numbers beyond 10, and lo and behold if my last project didn't have "eleven" and "twelve." Never say never!  :)

The main advantage of using arrays over string splitting is speed of execution. Strings such as you had in your code, though, are simpler to create. The code Tim provided is a mid-way between these two, as it first converts the string to an array then uses the array for further processing. You shouldn't have any issues breaking the Const across multiple lines, provided you start/stop each line with double quotes & continutation characters - as in: Const StrFind = "first,second,third," & _     "fourth,fifth,sixth," & _    "seventh,eighth,ninth"

I'm glad to see you're a night owl like me, Paul, since I'm working on these macros now! Thank you for the EXCELLENT and clear explanation. That answers a lot of questions, including a biggie in that I noticed after converting a few very long macros with MANY FindReplace sets to the StrFind-centric version, the macro did not appear to run faster, which is one thing I was hoping for (some docs are hundreds of pages, so it can take a while).
The break tip works great!
Meanwhile, I've been playing with trying to incorporate some wildcard behavior in the Array-centric version, with no luck.

I ran out of room in my comment, so here's part 2. I realize this the Array version is analyzing the text rather than doing a typical FindReplace operation, or so it appears. Is there a way to incorporate wildcards into this particular macro? I originally tried to just make minor changes to your original macro to sneak some FindReplace functions in there, and the macro blows up with every single change. So I'm stumped. Thanks so much for your help!

It's not the Array that's doing any text analysis - that's done by the Find. Do While .Find.Execute loop simply keeps executing the Find until it hits the end of the selected range. This loop is only needed because of the provision for multiple ordinals of each value being found and for the superscripting. And, yes, it's quite possible to use wildcards for both the Find and Replace arrays. See, for example: https://www.msofficeforums.com/168664-post2.html

Now I'm confused. It appears the example link you posted is using the SplitString method I started out with and not the Array method in your original post. Does that make sense? I was able to get Tim's SplitString sample to work simply by adding the WildCards=True option in the macro.
It appears your posted sample is similar to the SplitString method, which, I'm guessing, would not improve the playback speed of the macro, as your original Array sample would. I'm probably being clear as mud, I know! So maybe start with: How is your posted link sample different from Tim's sample?

I'm also wondering if the Len statements are coincidentally part of that sample macro because it pertains strictly to the intended purpose of that macro, or if that is always going to be required to use that macro. Does that make sense? I'll edit my original post in this thread to show a sample of my wildcard F/R using Tim's macro.

P.S. I'm going to likely be posting more code samples. My original post is going to turn into a train wreck of a word salad as this thread evolves, but since the comments must be kept short, I'm not sure how else to do it in this venue. I'm open to suggestions! :)

Yes, the code in the link is using the split method. Just different ways of skinning the same cat. The difference between the code in the link and what Tim did is the lack of an array conversion - Tim's arrF = Split(StrFind, ","), for example. Yes, the Len functions are peculiar to that macro. This example: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/7036-need-help-macro-looping.html is more typical. As for the additional questions - start new threds with one topic per thread.

I do see that. But after you explained the benefit of using the array method, my question is: Is it not possible to use your original array macro to do a wildcard replacement? Or are you saying I MUST use the split method if I want to incorporate wildcard functions into this macro? I hope that makes sense. :)

Thanks for your tip to start a new thread. I wasn't sure if it was a good idea to sort of micro-split this thread into (possibly) many "mini discussions" of a main theme. But I do have more questions, so I'll go and and do that. :)

You can definitely use an array with wildcards.

Okay. But not with your original array macro, right? I've tried every which way to Sunday to incorporate a wildcard function into that macro, with no luck.
For that original macro, it works perfectly as is, searching for "one through ten) and replacing "1 through 10." But I'm expanding beyond that into similar scenarios of, say, a "word as number" followed by a space and a number, replacing the word with a number and removing the space. So ...
six 23 = 623 (searching for "one space" through "ten space" followed by a number.

P.S. I'm motivated to use the array method after you said it had speedier playback than using the split string method. That would be significant with the 100+ page documents I'm working with.

I'm thinking this might be a good place to split off into a new thread, so I'll go ahead and do that now, and include the original macros in the thread. :)

I just posted a new thread to continue this discussion:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79046514/how-can-i-use-the-wildcard-function-in-a-word-vba-macro-with-an-array
