How can I use the wildcard function in a Word VBA macro with an array?
I posted a question [in another thread][1] asking for help to get a strSplit FindReplace macro working. Tim and Paul provided helpful answers and sample macros. Paul suggested one advantage of using an array method instead of strSplit  method is speedier playback. His array-centric sample also is able to be used with any amount of text selection, whereas my original strSplit  macro only works on one word, and if I select more, I run into that annoyance of Word wanting to replace the entire document and not just the selection.
Paul's array macro works great for exact matches, but now I would like to expand the options using the wildcard function with an array. Here is an example of code using the wildcard with the strSplit method to find a "word space number" string and replace with with a solid number with no space (e.g., "six 23" = "623").
Sub ecNUM_WSN_NumColNum()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Char As String
Call ClearFindAndReplaceParameters

'use const for fixed values
    Const StrFind = "([Oo]ne) ([0-9]),([Tt]wo) ([0-9]),([Tt]hree) ([0-9])," & _
        "([Ff]our) ([0-9]),([Ff]ive) ([0-9]),([Ss]ix) ([0-9]),([Ss]even) ([0-9])," & _
        "([Ee]ight) ([0-9]),([Nn]ine) ([0-9]),([Tt]en) ([0-9])"
    Const StrRepl = "1:\2,2:\2,3:\2,4:\2,5:\2,6:\2,7:\2,8:\2,9:\2,10:\2"
    
    Dim arrF, arrR, I As Long
    
    arrF = Split(StrFind, ",")
    arrR = Split(StrRepl, ",")

    Debug.Print "Checking: " & Selection.Text
    For I = LBound(arrF) To UBound(arrF)
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = arrF(I)
            .MatchWildcards = True
            .Replacement.Text = arrR(I)
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .IgnorePunct = True
            .IgnoreSpace = True
        If .Execute(Replace:=wdReplaceOne) Then Exit For  'found one!'
            Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
        End With
    Next I
    
Call ClearFindAndReplaceParameters
Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
Char = Selection.EndOf(Unit:=wdWord, Extend:=wdMove)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

The above code works great for a single selection. But if I choose several lines, for example, it only finds one selection because, of course, it includes the ReplaceOne instruction. If I change it to ReplaceAll (and remove the If statement), it wants to replace the entire document.
In the original thread, Paul's sample code for an exact-match scenario that works great for any amount of text selected:
Sub ReplaceNextOrdinal()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ArrFnd As Variant, ArrRep As Variant, RngFnd As Range, i As Long
'Array of Find expressions
ArrFnd = Array("first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth", "seventh", "eighth", "ninth", "tenth")
ArrRep = Array("1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th", "6th", "7th", "8th", "9th", "10th")
Set RngFnd = ActiveDocument.Range(Selection.Words.First.Start, Selection.Words.Last.End)
For i = 0 To UBound(ArrFnd)
  With RngFnd.Duplicate
    With .Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .IgnorePunct = True
      .IgnoreSpace = True
      .MatchWholeWord = True
      .Text = ArrFnd(i)
    End With
    Do While .Find.Execute
      If .InRange(RngFnd) Then
        .Text = ArrRep(i)
        .Start = .Characters.Last.Previous.Start
        .Font.Superscript = True
      Else
        Exit Do
      End If
    Loop
  End With
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

I have been trying to create a wildcard version of Paul's array method, without success. I either get a slew of compile errors, or it compiles and then does nothing. Below is my latest attempt with the Do While Loop stripped out because that is one place that kept triggering compile errors. I'm 99.99% I still need the loop, but the macro is not having it.
I plan to ultimately convert many dozens of macros currently with thousands of lines of code from the oh-so-basic endless string of FindReplace steps to these less-bloated split string and/or array versions. Some macros will be "single-use" versions (meaning I will use them for little bits of selected text while manually editing the document. Other macros will be used for global FindReplace functions (with no user intervention). I'm guessing I will need two separate versions of any macros that need to used in both scenarios. Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!
Karen :)
Sub ecNUM_WSN_NumColNum_ARRAY()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ArrFnd As Variant, ArrRep As Variant, RngFnd As Range, I As Long

'Array of Find expressions
ArrFnd = Array("([Oo]ne) ([0-9])", "([Tt]wo) ([0-9])", "([Tt]hree) ([0-9])", _
    "([Ff]our) ([0-9])", "([Ff]ive) ([0-9])", "([Ss]ix) ([0-9])", _
    "([Ss]even) ([0-9])", "([Ee]ight) ([0-9])", "([Nn]ine) ([0-9])", _
    "([Tt]en) ([0-9])", "([Ee]leven) ([0-9])", "([Tt]welve) ([0-9])", _
    "([Tt]hirteen) ([0-9])", "([Ff]ourteen) ([0-9])", "([Ff]ifteen) ([0-9])", _
    "([Ss]ixteen) ([0-9])", "([Ss]eventeen) ([0-9])", "([Ee]ighteen) ([0-9])", _
    "([Nn]ineteen) ([0-9])")
ArrRep = Array("1\2", "2\2", "3\2", "4\2", "5\2", "6\2", "7\2", "8\2", "9\2", _
    "10\2", "11\2", "12\2", "13\2", "14\2", "15\2", "16\2", "17\2", "18\2", "19\2")

Set RngFnd = ActiveDocument.Range(Selection.Words.First.Start, Selection.Words.Last.End)
Call ClearFindAndReplaceParameters
For I = 0 To UBound(ArrFnd)

  With RngFnd.Duplicate
        With .Find
            .Text = ArrFnd(I)
            .MatchWildcards = True
            .Replacement.Text = ArrRep(I)
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .IgnorePunct = True
            .IgnoreSpace = True
              End With
            RngFnd.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
Next I
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Word VBA macro with multiple find/replace options for single-word selection only works if the selection contains the first F/R option

Hi, johnsson - I should have been more detailed in my original post. You're correct that I did start out with ReplaceNextOrdinal . I no longer have the error-prone iterations to check for every error, but two I distinctly remember getting that drove me bonkers was "Next without For" and "End With without With." I stared at the macro 'til my eyes popped out and did not see anything wrong - everything was paired correctly, as far as I could tell. I'm now working with the new version Paul posted, and I'm about to post a question to him. Thanks for your response and effort to help! :)

To work with just a selected range, try:
Sub ecNUM_WSN_NumColNum_ARRAY()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ArrFnd As Variant, ArrRep As Variant, RngFnd As Range, i As Long
'Array of Find expressions
ArrFnd = Array("([Oo]ne) ([0-9])", "([Tt]wo) ([0-9])", "([Tt]hree) ([0-9])", _
    "([Ff]our) ([0-9])", "([Ff]ive) ([0-9])", "([Ss]ix) ([0-9])", _
    "([Ss]even) ([0-9])", "([Ee]ight) ([0-9])", "([Nn]ine) ([0-9])", _
    "([Tt]en) ([0-9])", "([Ee]leven) ([0-9])", "([Tt]welve) ([0-9])", _
    "([Tt]hirteen) ([0-9])", "([Ff]ourteen) ([0-9])", "([Ff]ifteen) ([0-9])", _
    "([Ss]ixteen) ([0-9])", "([Ss]eventeen) ([0-9])", "([Ee]ighteen) ([0-9])", _
    "([Nn]ineteen) ([0-9])")
ArrRep = Array("1\2", "2\2", "3\2", "4\2", "5\2", "6\2", "7\2", "8\2", "9\2", _
    "10\2", "11\2", "12\2", "13\2", "14\2", "15\2", "16\2", "17\2", "18\2", "19\2")
Set RngFnd = ActiveDocument.Range(Selection.Words.First.Start, Selection.Words.Last.End)
For i = 0 To UBound(ArrFnd)
  With RngFnd.Duplicate
    With .Find
      .Text = ArrFnd(i)
      .Replacement.Text = ArrRep(i)
      .MatchWildcards = True
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .IgnorePunct = True
      .IgnoreSpace = True
    End With
    Do While .Find.Execute
      If .InRange(RngFnd) Then
        .Collapse wdCollapseStart
        .Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      Else
        Exit Do
      End If
    Loop
End With
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

For a whole-of-document body approach, try:
Sub ecNUM_WSN_NumColNum_ARRAY()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ArrFnd As Variant, ArrRep As Variant, i As Long
'Array of Find expressions
ArrFnd = Array("([Oo]ne) ([0-9])", "([Tt]wo) ([0-9])", "([Tt]hree) ([0-9])", _
    "([Ff]our) ([0-9])", "([Ff]ive) ([0-9])", "([Ss]ix) ([0-9])", _
    "([Ss]even) ([0-9])", "([Ee]ight) ([0-9])", "([Nn]ine) ([0-9])", _
    "([Tt]en) ([0-9])", "([Ee]leven) ([0-9])", "([Tt]welve) ([0-9])", _
    "([Tt]hirteen) ([0-9])", "([Ff]ourteen) ([0-9])", "([Ff]ifteen) ([0-9])", _
    "([Ss]ixteen) ([0-9])", "([Ss]eventeen) ([0-9])", "([Ee]ighteen) ([0-9])", _
    "([Nn]ineteen) ([0-9])")
ArrRep = Array("1\2", "2\2", "3\2", "4\2", "5\2", "6\2", "7\2", "8\2", "9\2", _
    "10\2", "11\2", "12\2", "13\2", "14\2", "15\2", "16\2", "17\2", "18\2", "19\2")
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
  .MatchWildcards = True
  .Wrap = wdFindContinue
  .IgnorePunct = True
  .IgnoreSpace = True
  For i = 0 To UBound(ArrFnd)
    .Text = ArrFnd(i)
    .Replacement.Text = ArrRep(i)
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  Next i
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Hi Paul - Thanks for this new version! It works great except for the persistent Word quirkiness that makes me want to scream: ReplaceOne replaces only one instance of each word in the array within a selection (e.g., "one and two and one and three" = "1 and 2 and one and three"), and ReplaceAll replaces everything occurrence in the document, even without a selection. If I can get over that hurdle, I'll be cooking with gas! Thanks so much for your continued help! :)

Also, as I mentioned before, II plan to convert many macros to this array-centric version. I'm starting with the macros that expect to find selected text. But many of these related macros are global macros with no user intervention.
So I experimented with modifying your macro to do a global F/R, and with just two changes - ReplaceOne to ReplaceAll and changing the Set statement to RngFnd = ActiveDocument.Content - it works great! But I wonder why that version changes ALL occurrences, but the other version only changes the first instance of each word in the array, even with ReplaceAll?

See updated answer.

UPDATE: After cycling through many nuanced changes in pursuit of getting the desired result of "replace just this one word in this small selection" or "replace all occurrences of potential F/R choices but ONLY within the (larger random) selection, and NOT the whole document" I believe I have found success.
I made single change to your original macro: changing the wrap to FindContinue instead of FindStop. I'm puzzled that the change worked because with F/R macros that I typically make, I need to use FindStop to limit the F/R behavior. But I'm happy it's working! Thanks so much, Paul!

I should clarify that single change solved BOTH the problem of ensuring that the F/R replace ONLY occurs within the selection, AND it also replaces (within the selection) ALL occurrences of the searched-for items (e.g., "three and one and three and four and three" to 3 and 1 and 3 and 4 and 3") instead of just the first occurrence. Yay to that! :)

My apologies - I didn't see that  you posted a new answer. I just tried it, and it works beautifully. THANKS SO MUCH! I'm beyond excited to have all the versions of these macros working. I'm crossing my fingers that the global macros will, indeed, run faster after the transformation is complete. But even if it's a breakeven timewise, I'm still oh-so-happy to eliminate thousands of lines of code and end up with macros that are much easier to digest visually and modify. THANK YOU SO MUCH! :)

P.S. I think I did mention in a previous post that I wondered my changing the range to in your original macro to ActiveDocument.Content for global F/R rendered any other statements unnecessary, and in comparing that version to your actual posted global F/R version, I see that you did eliminate the Do While Loop statements. When I tried to do that, I think it compiled okay, but the nothing was replaced. I also notice that you moved the Next I statement to inside the With/End With statement. That's where I ran into a lot of trouble- trying to figure out how and what statements to group. :)

P.P.S. I also want to note that if I use your selected range version, with wdFindStop, it only replaces one instance of any found item in a selection (so a selection of "one and three and one" results in "1 and 3 and one"). If I change it to wdFindContinue, it replaces everything in the selection without going out of bounds to the rest of the document. I find that puzzling because wdFindStop is usually key to taming F/R statements to stay inside the lines, so it's a puzzle that (1) wdFindStop wouldn't work and (2) wdFindContinue wouldn't cause it to do the entire document. Quirky Word! :)

It replaces all of them for me...

Are you referring to the "selected range" version? I'm going bonkers. This has been happening throughout this entire process where I'll get a certain behavior, then make changes and get a different behavior, then when I change things back to the previous way, the behavior I "remember" getting is now different.
Case in point: I was just repeating the steps tin slow motion a few different ways to report back to you, and low and behold if now it's different! Now I'm getting a "hybrid" result ... (continued in part 2 below)

Part 2 of 2: I created some text and selected only the text up to the //:
one and three and four and one // and two and seven and one
one and three and four and one and two and seven and one
With FindOne/ReplaceOne, it replaces just the selection, but only the first "one." With FindContinue/ReplaceOne, it also replaces the next one, three, four, but not the rest, none of which are selected.
Scratching my head! :)

Oh, my goodness. The macro gremlins are running rampant tonight! I'm still cycling through options every which way to Sunday, trying to get the desired behavior as well as replicate any problems. In the process, I wanted to make sure all the code was still identical to your original "selected version." So just to be safe, I replaced my current code with the text from your post. (Set RngFnd to Next I). And lo and behold, it's working like it's supposed to for selections (with FindStop)! So I think we're good now, although I can't explain what was going on with the crazy results! :)

The "selected range" version should work in any scenario, right? Meaning wildcard, no wildcard (so statement removed), match case, whole word, etc.?
I don't see anything in the macro that indicates it would only work in a wildcard search. I created a test macro with a simple find array of one, two, three and replace with 1, 2, 3, and the ONLY other change is to remove or comment out .MatchWildcards = True. Selecting a line that contains "one and two and three and one and two and three and one and two and three," it replaces the middle "one and two and three" and nothing else. Strange!

Are you using the update of the 'selected range version? I updated that and supplied the whole-of-document version together. The updated 'selected range' version replaces all matching strings in the selected range, no matter how many of each there are. Depending on what you're working with, the wildcard option can be used with ordinary text - where you want exact matches, for example. But if you set .MatchWildcards = False with either version and specify whatever other Find/Replace parameters you need, the code will work just fine.

Me again, Paul. I posted a link to an unlisted YouTube vid to demo what is happening when I use your two latest macros. FYI, I'm leaving in a few hours for a weeklong vacay, so will probably not respond again before then. Thanks for your help!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sXItzauZbO8

I hadn't seen that behavior before. Fixed by adding .Start = RngFnd.Start to the code.

That worked! THANK YOU SO MUCH, Paul! I'm doing the happy dance just in time to put the dust cover on this while I go on the vacay with my family!  :)

P.S. Just to be sure that I put it in the right place, I added it as the first statement after the If statement, so it's between If .InRange... and .Find.Execute...   Correct?

Yes, as shown in the posted code.

Ah! I didn't realize you had updated the code. I'm struggling to keep up with the updates to this thread, trying to make sure I don't miss anything! Thanks for the confirmation and the updated code. Now I'm really shutting down my computer and heading for the airport! :)

I subsequently realised that a better solution would be to use .Collapse wdCollapseStart, because that will work better where only formatting changes are being applied. See revised code.

Please, try replacing
If .Execute(Replace:=wdReplaceOne) Then Exit For  'found one!'
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne

with
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll


Hi, FaneDuru - I pointed out in my original post that if I use the ReplaceAll function, I get the undesired results of every instance in the document being replaced. So there's that as far as using the strSplit function. But for purposes of this post, I'm also primarily interested in using the array function instead of the strSplit function. I also like that with Paul's  original macro, it works for any amount of text selected - one word, one several lines, or the whole document. But I can't get it to work with wildcards. Thanks for your response. :)

@HappyNanaMO 1. Do you manually select a range and then you run the code? 2. If so, did you try the above suggestion or you considered that it is the same with your attempt to use wdReplaceAll? It must replace All occurrences only inside selection. 3. If not, what do you mean by selection?

Hi FaneDuru - For some of these macros (there will be many based on the same find/replace principles), I will only ever need one version that expects to find selected text when the macro is run. For others, I will need a "selected text" version and a version that does a global F/R without user intervention.
The problem I have with all the macros so far is the typical Word quirk: ReplaceOne only replaces one occurrence of each word in the array, and ReplaceAll, even within a selection, mostly (but weirdly, not always), replaces all occurrences in the document. Thanks for your help! :)

Did you try my above suggestion?

Hi, FaneDuru - I did try your suggestion, and it replaced all instances in the document. :)

My apologies for not updating you on that status. :)

@HappyNanaMO But, it must replace all occurrences FROM SELECTION! Did you select part of the text and run the code and it deletes all all occurrences IN ALL THE DOCUMENT? This does not make any sense. I tested it many times and it behave as I say... Now, what expectation do  you have when you do not select part of the document? Your code, as it is processes A SELECTION.

Hi, FaneDuru - I'm expecting to have two versions of these macros for most scenarios: a selection version and a whole document version.
For the whole document version, my expectation is I will never select any text.
For the selection version, my expectation is I will have some text selected - one word, several words, a whole line, several lines - and every occurrence of any item in the array will be changed.
I posted a link to a vid in my response to Paul to demo what's happening. Thanks for your help! :)
FYI: New responses will be delayed until I return from vacay next week. :)

I originally missed the part about limiting the replacement scope. In my example I used ActiveDocument.Content, but this could be replaced with a Selection object.
Maybe something like this would work for you
Function reverseArray(sourceArray As Variant) As Collection
    Dim reversed As Collection
    Dim i As Integer
    
    Set reversed = New Collection
    For i = LBound(sourceArray) To UBound(sourceArray)
        reversed.Add i, sourceArray(i)
    Next i
    Set reverseArray = reversed
End Function
Sub justNumbers()
    Dim numList
    Dim numMatches As String
    Dim numRegEx As RegExp
    Dim matches, matchedItem As Object
    Dim numForItem As New Collection
    Dim replacementText As String
    
    numList = Array("zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eigth", "nine")
    Set numForItem = reverseArray(numList)
    numMatches = Join(numList, "|")
    
    
    Set numRegEx = New RegExp
    With numRegEx
        .Pattern = "(" & numMatches & ")(\s)([0-9]{1,})"
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
    End With

    Set matches = numRegEx.Execute(ActiveDocument.Content.Text)
    For Each matchedItem In matches
        replacementText = numForItem.Item(matchedItem.SubMatches(0)) & matchedItem.SubMatches(2)
        ActiveDocument.Content.Find.Execute FindText:=matchedItem, ReplaceWith:=replacementText, Replace:=wdReplaceOne
    Next matchedItem
End Sub


Hi user27589787 - That's an interesting solution! I tried to run it and received a compile error: "User-defined type not defined," and it highlighted the macro name. Step Into takes me to the Dim numRegEx As RegExp statement. Any ideas?
Also, am I correct in assuming the "(\s)" in the .Pattern expression statement represents a regular space? The only time I've ever seen "s" used in wildcard/reg ex statements is as "^s" to represent a nonbreaking space. I did not know you could use it alone to represent just plain white space.
Thanks for your effort to help! :)

To use regular expressions you have to add an include for the Microsoft VBScript RegEx library (under Tools>References).
The regex grammar is more expressive than Find, so definitely worth exploring. The rub with VBA is that RegEx is better than Find at finding, but worse with replacements. Here's an alternative solution that combines regex for search with Find for replacements and that is designed for handling a big Or situation like you described in your later post. It uses a dictionary for matches and replacements, which gets passed to the search/replace subroutine. This would make it clear and easy to maintain for long lists like you described. For example:
Sub replaceNumberWords()
    Dim replacements As Scripting.Dictionary
    
    Set replacements = New Scripting.Dictionary
    replacements("first") = "1st"
    replacements("second") = "2nd"
    replacements("third") = "3rd"
    replacements("fourth") = "4th"
    
    Call OrGroupReReplace(ActiveDocument.Content, replacements)
End Sub

Here is the subroutine that does the actual work (you'll need to add a reference for the MS Scripting Runtime to use Dictionaries). I passed it the entire document for search/replace but it will accept a selection range as well.
Sub OrGroupReReplace(searchRange As Range, replacements As Scripting.Dictionary)
    Dim searchRegex As RegExp
    Dim matchItem, matches As Object
    Dim startPos As Long
    Dim endPos As Long
    Dim fieldRanges As Collection
    Dim fieldRange As Range
    Dim fieldIndex As Integer
    Dim inField As Boolean
    Dim docField As field
    Dim searchString, replacementText As String

    ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = True
    
    Set searchRegex = New RegExp
    searchString = "\b(" & Join(replacements.Keys, "|") & ")\b"
    With searchRegex
        .pattern = searchString
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
    End With
    
    Set fieldRanges = New Collection
    For Each docField In searchRange.Fields
        fieldRanges.Add docField.Code
    Next docField

    Set matches = searchRegex.Execute(searchRange.Text)
    fieldIndex = 1

    For i = matches.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        replacementText = replacements(LCase(matches(i)))
        startPos = matches(i).FirstIndex
        endPos = startPos + matches(i).Length
        
        Do While fieldIndex <= fieldRanges.Count
            Set fieldRange = fieldRanges(fieldIndex)
            If endPos <= fieldRange.Start Then
                Exit Do
            ElseIf startPos >= fieldRange.End Then
                fieldIndex = fieldIndex + 1
            Else
                inField = True
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
        
        If Not inField Then
            searchRange.Find.Execute FindText:=matches(i), ReplaceWith:=replacementText, Replace:=wdReplaceOne
        End If
        inField = False
    Next i
    
    ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = False
End Sub


user27589787 - This is fascinating. I don't have time to play with it now, as I'm leaving in just a few hours for a weeklong vacay. I will try it out when I return and let you know what happens. Thanks so much! :)
